# MVC5 codefirst adding a user to many-many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Im using mvc5 with codefirst and the user account stuff.

I have a simple requirement a user can belong to multiple stores and a business can have multiple stores.

So far I have the business - many stores working but I cant seem to figure out how to setup the users.

My StoreModel

```
    public virtual Business Business { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Employees { get; set; }
```

My BusinessModel

```
    public virtual ICollection<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; }
```

Within my context I have tried

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    //a user can belong to multiple stores
    public virtual ICollection<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; }
}
```

however when I try add-migration the code generated is going to change my table names and does create the join table between Store & AspNetUser

My migration looks like

```
  public override void Up()
    {
        RenameTable(name: "dbo.Stores", newName: "ApplicationUserStoreModels");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Stores", "ApplicationUser_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers");
        DropIndex("dbo.Stores", new[] { "ApplicationUser_Id" });
        CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicationUserStoreModels", "ApplicationUser_Id");
        CreateIndex("dbo.ApplicationUserStoreModels", "StoreModel_StoreId");
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUserStoreModels", "ApplicationUser_Id", "dbo.AspNetUsers", "Id", cascadeDelete: true);
        AddForeignKey("dbo.ApplicationUserStoreModels", "StoreModel_StoreId", "dbo.Stores", "StoreId", cascadeDelete: true);
        DropColumn("dbo.Stores", "ApplicationUser_Id");
    }
```

Can anyone help what I need to do to get this working?

Comment: You might need to write some `FluentAPI` to get exactly what you want, personally, I've never been able to get many-to-many working the way I want them to without using `FluentAPI`

Comment: @SOfanatic when we use fluent api do we need to specify the navigation properties in the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can either just not have a store table and put a list in each appuser and business and EF will make your many to many relationship or you can use fluent api to map everything. Should be something like the following.

```
 public class Business
{
    public virtual ICollection<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; }
}
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; }
}




public class StoreModel {
public string ApplicationUserId { get; set; }
public int BusinessId { get; set; }

public virtual Business Businesss { get; set; }
public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{   base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
modelBuilder.Entity<StoreModel>().HasKey(e => new { e.ApplicationUserId, e.BusinessId});
}
```

Comment: when we use fluent api do we need to specify the navigation properties in the models?